# setFormula() in script editor with spaces in sheets referenced by the formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

When i put a formula on script editor using setFormula() function, where the formula contains spaces like 'ABC List'!, it shows a syntax error when the script is saved.

I saw answers that mention putting a + till it looks like '+ABC List+'! but that didnt work as well (and even if it did, the formula wouldn't work on a normal cell).

I'm curious - is there no way to write formulas which reference sheets with spaces in their names in script editor?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange("G14").setFormula('\'January 2017\'!A1');
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Reports').getRange("G15").setFormula("'January 2017'!A1");
```